# How many marbles?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm, least-common-multiple

One dozen of big marbles and small marbles is 132 gram. If one big marbles is 3 gram heavier than one small marbles, then specify the possibilities of how many are the big marbles and the small marbles.

I got $x+y=12$, $ax+by=132$, and $a=3+b$
with $x$ is how many big marbles, $y$ is small marbles, $a$ and $b$ are their mass. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: I think your third equation should be $a=3+b$

Comment: Currently, the problem is underdefined. All solutions for $y=4b-32$ are viable.

Comment: Oh yes I made a mistake and also the question didn't ask for a define answer, but just the possibility of how many they are. I'm sorry, I translated the question on my own from another language, so I left some things.

Comment: You can edit your question. Do you still need help?

Comment: I think I got it... I found that if $t$ is an integer, then $a=12+t$, $b=9+t$, $x=8-4t$, and $y=4+4t$

Comment: That may be right, Fifi, but surely you need to impose some restrictions on $t$ (since, for example, $x$ can't be negative).

Comment: So I just need to add $t\in{\Bbb Z+}$?

Comment: No, $t=3$ is a positive integer, but $x=8-4t$ isn't. It's not $t$ that can't be negative, it's $a,b,x,y$ that can't be negative.

Comment: Oh! If $x,y,a,b$ must be positive and there are two kinds of marbles ($x>0$ and $y>0$), then $t$ must be $1$

Comment: It's not clear to me from the wording that they have to be positive. They can't be negative, but that doesn't mean they're positive.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted yesterday, Fifi?

Comment: Are you still here, Fifi?

Comment: It said that it is a dozen of big marbles and small marbles together. So there must be at least one of each. That what I was thinking.

Comment: OK, Fifi, but what about my answer? If there must be at least one of each, my answer still says there are eleven solutions, and tells you what they are. Is that OK?

Comment: Earth to Fifi: Come in, please.

Comment: Please engage, Fifi.

Answer (score 1):

Let's express everything in terms of $b$. We have $a=b+3$. Putting that in the second equation gives $(b+3)x+by=132$, which is $3x+b(x+y)=132$, but from the first equation $x+y=12$, so $3x+12b=132$, so $x=44-4b$. Then $y=12-x=4b-32$.

Now, we need $x\ge0$, so $b\le11$, and $y\ge0$, so $b\ge8$. So, $8\le b\le11$. Further, $x$ and $y$ need to be whole numbers, so $4b$ must be a whole number, so $b$ must be one of the 13 numbers $8,33/4,17/2,\dots,11$. For each such $b$, you can use the formulas already derived to work out $x$, $y$, and $a$.

EDIT: The upshot is that $x$ can be any whole number between zero and twelve, inclusive. Then $y=12-x$, $b=11-(x/4)$, and $a=14-(x/4)$.

MORE EDIT: If you read the question to imply there must be at least one marble of each of the two types, then $x$ can be any whole number between one and eleven, inclusive (and $y,b,a$ are given by the formula above).